# Exoplayer 2 AMR Format using FFmpeg extension

Tags: android, exoplayer, android-ffmpeg, exoplayer2.x

I've build the exoplayer ffmpeg extension and added to my project, because i need to support AMR format, so:

Following the tutorial: [FFmpeg Extension](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/tree/release-v2/extensions/ffmpeg)

```
COMMON_OPTIONS="\
    ...
    --enable-decoder=amrnb \
    --enable-decoder=amrwb \
    ...
```

After the compilation step:

```
cd "${FFMPEG_EXT_PATH}"/jni && \
${NDK_PATH}/ndk-build APP_ABI="armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a x86" -j4
```

I've generated aar file with:

```
./gradlew :extensions-ffmpeg:assembleDebug
```

So I got the **extension-ffmpeg-debug.arr** file generated and put it in the lib folder of my project.

My player implementation:

```
public class DefaultPlayer {

    private ExoPlayer player;

    //"flac" "amr" "wma" "wav" "3gp" "mp3"

    public DefaultPlayer(Context context) {

        DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
        playerInit(context, bandwidthMeter);

        try {
            testFormat(context);
        } catch (RawResourceDataSource.RawResourceDataSourceException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void testFormat(Context context) throws RawResourceDataSource.RawResourceDataSourceException {

        Uri uri = RawResourceDataSource.buildRawResourceUri(R.raw.sample_flac);
        final RawResourceDataSource dataSource = new RawResourceDataSource(context);
        dataSource.open(new DataSpec(uri));

        DefaultExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
        ExtractorMediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(uri, new DataSource.Factory() {
            @Override
            public DataSource createDataSource() {
                return dataSource;
            }
        }, extractorsFactory, null, null);

        player.prepare(mediaSource);
        player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
    }

    private void playerInit(Context context, DefaultBandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter) {

        TrackSelection.Factory videoTrackSelectionFactory = new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter);
        TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(videoTrackSelectionFactory);

        player = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(context, trackSelector);
        player.addListener(new PlayerEventListener());
    }
}
```

The error:

```
08-04 16:03:53.405 10873-10918/br.com.andersonsilva.musicmodel E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Source error.
                                                                                        com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor, FlacExtractor) could read the stream.
                                                                                            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:774)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:697)
                                                                                            at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-04 16:03:53.406 10873-10873/br.com.andersonsilva.musicmodel D/MUSIC: event: PlayerErrorEvent{error=com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException}
08-04 16:03:53.407 10873-10873/br.com.andersonsilva.musicmodel D/MUSIC: event: PlayerStateChangedEvent{playWhenReady=true, playbackState=1}
```

What else should be configured to run the AMR format, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: did you enable decoder for the required types in your configure script? such as `–enable-decoder=amrnb` for `AMR-NB` or `–enable-decoder=amrwb` for `AMR-WB`

Comment: @UlugToprak yes, I did!

Comment: Hi @AndersonK ,  can you send me the aar file?